# Can Activity classes be made launchable only during development/debug?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view, android-testing

A common situation I face is that I wish to test a custom `View` visibly on screen while it is being developed as part of a large application. I realise that unit testing exists, particularly using `ActivityUnitTestCase`, but as far as I understand these frameworks don't actually attach the components visibly on screen.

At present, the way I tend to do this is to just place the component wherever it will actually be used within the application. This often means needing to wait some time for the application to start or to navigate through parts of the application before it is visible, which can become cumbersome.

The better way I've found is to create an `Activity` within the application that exists purely for test purposes (e.g. to simply display a custom `View` I'm developing), which is launched to display the custom `View` (or whatever) that I am working on. To do this, the only intent filter I've assigned to that `Activity` in the manifest is `android.intent.action.MAIN`, and *not* `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`. Then, I can simply create a Run/Debug Configuration in Android Studio to launch that `Activity` directly. This, *as far as I believe*, effectively allows me to have `Activity` classes which may only be launched by me from the IDE.

My questions are:

1. Does omitting `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` guarantee that users of the application won't be able to launch that `Activity` by any means nor be aware of its existence? Is this a safe to have `Activity` classes for development only?
2. Is there a workflow or test framework of any kind I could use to improve on how I am doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I realise that unit testing exists, particularly using ActivityUnitTestCase, but as far as I understand these frameworks don't actually attach the components visibly on screen.

Well, `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` does, as does the new `ActivityTestRule`. I don't recall playing with `ActivityUnitTestCase`.

> Does omitting android.intent.category.LAUNCHER guarantee that users of the application won't be able to launch that Activity by any means nor be aware of its existence?

No. It won't be easy for them to start it, but it is exported and has an `<intent-filter>`, so somebody could find a way.

> Is this a safe to have Activity classes for development only?

I would put them in your `debug` sourceset, assuming that you are using Android Studio. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Diagnostics/Activity) that has a production launcher activity in `main` and a diagnostic activity in `debug`. In a `release` build, the diagnostic activity does not even ship.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't declared some value like

```
public static boolean IS_DEBUG = true;
```

then in any part you want to show it, just put in condition like

```
if (IS_DEBUG) {
    your_develop_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //...
}
else {
    your_develop_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

after you finish develop. before you publish, just change

```
IS_DEBUG = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of defining your own IS_DEBUG, just use BuildConfig.DEBUG